# Using two cell values to read value from a thrid cell depending on the two cells previously mentioned

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table which is composed of a Column with values along the Y axis (call it B) and one with values corresponding to X axis (call them A).

Where B corresponds to column values (1, 2, 3..), A to row values (X,Y,Z..) 
Each cell in the table has some numeric value.

I want people to be able to specify A and B values where excel then picks out the correct cell depending on what the user specified.

The values entered by the user are exact (eg. 1003) whereas the values of A are as multiple of 50 (eg. 950, 1000, 1050). Same thing goes for the other (B) specified cell (but as a multiple of 0.5 instead of 50).

I have used MROUND to circumvent this. Now I'm left with having to get the correct cell value extracted from a table I made in a different worksheet (I have specified the range as well).

The two values are being processed independenty (ie A and B value in this case).

What can I do to get excel to pick out the correct "third" value from the table/range?

I was thinking that if I can match the value to the correct value in the range and then get the row+column number I can translate this into a cell-name. But it seems very complicated and I'm not entirely sure how to do it. Is there a better way? If so I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.. I can try to figure it out myself but I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($A:$D,MATCH(G2,$A:$A,0),MATCH(F2,$1:$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Only thing I would change is to reduce the ranges only to the size of the table. In this instance it makes no difference, but if his table is located somewhere else on the sheet and there is other unrelated data to the upper-left of the table, it is possible that the result would return something unexpected since `MATCH` only returns the first instance that it finds. This problem is avoided entirely if only exact table ranges are used. Otherwise I agree with your answer. +1

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked perfectly, substituted the open colym/row range with specific named ranges and it worked perfectly! Appreciate the help tremendously!